# Searchkick: including some where clauses in smart_aggs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-6, searchkick

How would I use some filters when using `aggs` but not others? If I use `smart_aggs: false`, no filters are used in the `aggs` count.

By default, where conditions apply to aggregations.

```
Product.search "wingtips", where: {color: "brandy"}, aggs: [:size]
# aggregations for brandy wingtips are returned
```

Change this with:

```
Product.search "wingtips", where: {color: "brandy"}, aggs: [:size], smart_aggs: false
# aggregations for all wingtips are returned
```

Need to allow income some where but not others in the count

```
Product.search "wingtips", where_no_aggs_count: {country_availability: "us"}, where_aggs_count: {color: "brandy"}, aggs: [:size], smart_aggs: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Query and aggregations are linked in Elasticsearch.
If you want 2 different contexts, you'll have to do 2 different requests.